# Error Enter Valid date at cart price rule and save it db, after adding time in date picker in Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, database, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.6, datepicker

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="rule_information" sortOrder="10">
        <field name="from_date" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="to_date" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is my sales_rule_form.xml
i changed dB column as VARCHAR/datetime, its showing invalid date, and how can i save it in db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. Try following way for the fix:

> **app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Date">
        <plugin name="SR_MagentoCommunity::allow_format_from_config"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Date" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> **app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Ui/Component/Form/Element/DataType/Date.ph**

```
code>
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType;

class Date
{
    public function aroundPrepare(
        \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Date $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $configOrig = $subject->getData('config');
        $proceed();
        $config = $subject->getData('config');
        if (isset($configOrig['options']) && isset($configOrig['options']['dateFormat'])) {
            $config['options']['dateFormat'] = $configOrig['options']['dateFormat'];
        }

        if (isset($configOrig['options']) && isset($configOrig['options']['timeFormat'])) {
            $config['options']['timeFormat'] = $configOrig['options']['timeFormat'];
        }

        $subject->setData('config', $config);
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Save" type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Save"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Save.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote;

class Save extends \Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Save
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\DateTime
     */
    private $dateTimeFilter;

    /**
     * Save constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\DateTime $dateTimeFilter
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\DateTime $dateTimeFilter
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry, $fileFactory, $dateFilter);
        $this->dateTimeFilter = $dateTimeFilter;
    }

    /**
     * Promo quote save action
     *
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getPostValue()) {
            try {
                /** @var $model \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule */
                $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::class);
                $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                    'adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save',
                    ['request' => $this->getRequest()]
                );
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

                $filterValues = ['from_date' => $this->dateTimeFilter];
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('to_date')) {
                    $filterValues['to_date'] = $this->dateTimeFilter;
                }
                $inputFilter = new \Zend_Filter_Input(
                    $filterValues,
                    [],
                    $data
                );
                $data = $inputFilter->getUnescaped();

                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
                if ($id) {
                    $model->load($id);
                    if ($id != $model->getId()) {
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The wrong rule is specified.'));
                    }
                }

                $session = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Backend\Model\Session::class);

                $validateResult = $model->validateData(new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($data));
                if ($validateResult !== true) {
                    foreach ($validateResult as $errorMessage) {
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($errorMessage);
                    }
                    $session->setPageData($data);
                    $this->_redirect('sales_rule/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId()]);
                    return;
                }

                if (isset(
                        $data['simple_action']
                    ) && $data['simple_action'] == 'by_percent' && isset(
                        $data['discount_amount']
                    )
                ) {
                    $data['discount_amount'] = min(100, $data['discount_amount']);
                }
                if (isset($data['rule']['conditions'])) {
                    $data['conditions'] = $data['rule']['conditions'];
                }
                if (isset($data['rule']['actions'])) {
                    $data['actions'] = $data['rule']['actions'];
                }
                unset($data['rule']);
                $model->loadPost($data);

                $useAutoGeneration = (int)(
                    !empty($data['use_auto_generation']) && $data['use_auto_generation'] !== 'false'
                );
                $model->setUseAutoGeneration($useAutoGeneration);

                $session->setPageData($model->getData());

                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the rule.'));
                $session->setPageData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('sales_rule/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId()]);
                    return;
                }
                $this->_redirect('sales_rule/*/');
                return;
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
                if (!empty($id)) {
                    $this->_redirect('sales_rule/*/edit', ['id' => $id]);
                } else {
                    $this->_redirect('sales_rule/*/new');
                }
                return;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the rule data. Please review the error log.')
                );
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Backend\Model\Session::class)->setPageData($data);
                $this->_redirect('sales_rule/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id')]);
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('sales_rule/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sohel Rana, Thank you for your support. Here it fixed validation part. but its not saving it giving error **Something went wrong while saving the rule data. Please review the error log.** but no error in console & Network.

Comment: Can you show me the error from the log?

Comment: "Navigated to http://127.0.0.1/Magento1/admin/sales_rule/promo_quote/edit/key/6078bde17a5d4000236f9cc1333e9def558e187ec6dc2f093370c438f016e20d/
jquery-migrate.js:21 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active".. No error here

Comment: This is not what I am asking. Find log from system.log or exception.log or reports?

Comment: `[2019-02-18 05:23:13] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '2019-02-26T05:21:00.000Z' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '2019-02-26T05:21:00.000Z' at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Magento1\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Stdlib\\DateTime\\Filter\\Date.php:69)"} []
`Exception log

Comment: system.log `[2019-02-18 05:28:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []`

Comment: No worries, I got it now :). I will post fixing when I am free.

Comment: You need to change date to datetime for to_date and from_date column in DB. After that check updated answer.

Comment: only date is saving in DB, time is `00:00:00`, no errors in exception log, system log shows, `[2019-02-18 11:41:46] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []`, Thank you @Sohel Rana for responce

Comment: Really? for my case, this is working fine. From date is 2019-02-18 11:09:00, and to date is 2019-02-18 18:09:00

Comment: Clear all cheches if have

Comment: @Sahel Rana ,Thank you very much you solved this issue. very thankful to you :)